# What will happen when we move the time integration out of space norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $f(\mathbf{x},t)\in L^2\big((t_1,t_2);\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)\big)$, how to prove the following inequality?

$$
\Bigg\|\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(\mathbf{x},t)dt\Bigg\|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)} \le \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\Bigg\|f(\mathbf{x},t)\Bigg\|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)}dt.
$$

The above result is simlar to
$$
\Bigg|\int_a^b f(x) dx\Bigg| \le \int_a^b\Bigg|f(x) \Bigg|dx. 
$$

Comment: For which functions can you prove the inequality quiet easily? Or how is (strong-)measurabilty defined in such spaces?

Comment: I have seen someone used this result in the paper, however, I don't kown how to prove it.

Comment: Inner product and norm in $L^2\big((t_1,t_2);\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)\big)$ are define as follows. For any $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \in L^2\big((t_1,t_2);\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)\big)$,  $$(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}):=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}~d\mathbf{x}dt,$$ $$\|\mathbf{u}\|:=\sqrt{(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u})}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the norm of vector $x$ in a Hilbert space is equal to $\sup \langle x,y\rangle$ where the supremum is taken over all unit vectors $y$. Let $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ be a unit norm function (we can even choose it smooth, with compact support). Then 
 $$\left\langle  \int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(\cdot,t)\,dt ,  g \right\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)} 
 = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\,dt \int_\Omega f(\mathbf x,t)g(\mathbf x)\,d\mathbf x 
 $$
 The latter does not exceed
$$\begin{split}
  \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\,dt \int_\Omega |f(\mathbf x,t)|\,|g(\mathbf x)|\,d\mathbf x 
 &\le \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \|f(\cdot, t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|g\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \,dt 
 \\&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \|f(\cdot, t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}   \,dt 
\end{split}$$
as desired.